# Ios Video Effect

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, video, avfoundation

I want to add a effect on video  on ios app , but i dunno what to search for , what i want exactly is the funny face effect , mutate face from front camera, so what i could search for , am using the avfoundation.

any clue that i can start with ?

thanks

example :http://a5.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Purple/v4/1e/30/94/1e309460-d337-cc43-5f68-3912d755466f/screen320x480.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its applying filters on it.

There is open source library which help you to develop this, But obvious you need to apply your own logic and open GL.

[GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

[CoreImage Framework](https://maniacdev.com/ios-5-sdk-tutorial-and-guide/core-image-example)